# NullPointerException when calling super.onCreateView() in MiniControllerFragment

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-cast

In my app I'm trying [to implement a MiniControlFragment](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#6) which is shown when the user decides to close `ExpandedControlsActivity` (a full-screen version of Mini controller). Instead of adding it declaratively to the xml layout I need to do that programmatically.

So I created own class which extends `MiniControllerFragment`:

```
public class CastControllingFragment extends MiniControllerFragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle)
    {
        View view = super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, viewGroup, bundle);
        if (view != null) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            view.setLayoutParams(frameLayoutParams);
        }
        return view;
    }

    public static void show(FragmentActivity activity) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.castMiniController) == null)
        {
            View rootView = activity.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
            if (rootView instanceof ViewGroup)
            {                    
               fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new CastControllingFragment()).commit();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I instantiate it and add it to the fragment transaction in `Activity`'s `onResume` callback:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        CastControllingFragment.show(this);
        super.onResume();
    }
```

This is the `Activity`'s layout with `FrameLayout` as container for my fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But, when the `super.onCreateView()` in my `CastControllingFragment` is called then I get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3400)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3440)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2713)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null
>   array
>                                                                                         at
>   com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment.zza(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment.onCreateView(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.google.sample.cast.refplayer.CastControllingFragment.onCreateView(CastControllingFragment.java:22)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1682)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:499)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:175)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6792)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3377)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3440) 
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2713) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a change in the latest Cast SDK that made it incompatible (crashing) with older versions of Google Play Services.
Unfortunately, even cast sample app crashes when using latest Cast SDK with outdated GPS (or on emulators).
The issue has been discussed here: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/issues/12

The solution is to check Google Play Services version before initialising any cast components, including mini controller (i.e. you can't just put mini controller fragment into your xml layout file - you either have to inflate it dynamically, or have two layout files - one with, and one without your mini controller).

Code to check GPS version:

```
GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
isGPSAvailable = (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS);
```

If the results is not `ConnectionResult.SUCCESS`, don't initialise your `MiniControllerFragment`.

Also, please keep in mind that it is **not** possible to instantiate `MiniControllerFragment` using `new MiniControllerFragment()`. You have to inflate it from xml or you will get `NullPointerException`.

There are two ways to inflate `MiniControllerFragment`:

1. Create separate xml layout files and inflate appropriate one in your `Activity.onCreate`:

   ```
   setContentView(isGPSAvailable ? R.layout.activity_main_with_controller : R.layout.activity_main_without_controller);
   ```
2. Create `ViewStub` in your layout pointing to `MiniControllerFragment` and inflate it only when you have play services.

activity layout:

```
<ViewStub
android:id="@+id/cast_minicontroller"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout="@layout/cast_mini_controller_fragment"
/>
```

cast_mini_controller_fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/castMiniController"
          class="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:visibility="gone"/>
```

code in your activity `onCreate()`:

```
ViewStub miniControllerStub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.cast_minicontroller);
if (isGPSAvailable) {
    miniControllerStub.inflate();
}
```

I prefer the `ViewStub` approach as it does not duplicate your layouts.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, great clarification :)

Comment: nice approach with the stub

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.

```
 private void displayViewFromDrawer(int position, @Nullable String  textTitle) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position){
        case 1: //Activity record
            ActivityFragment.newInstance(current_date_string);
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment,"fragment_container");
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

This is ActivityFragment example

```
 public class ActivityFragment extends Fragment{
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_main, container, false);

   //In here you can cast TextViews,Buttons,etc...

   return v;
 }

  public static ActivityFragment newInstance(String date) {
    ActivityFragment fragment = new ActivityFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", date);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cristian, I tried your solution but I´m still getting the same error